Trouble binding src attribute of embed tag in Angular
I'm trying to dynamically bind the src attribute of an embed tag in Angular using property binding, but it's not working as expected.
Here's what I've tried:
In my TypeScript file, I have declared a property to hold the source URL:
export class MyComponent {
 embedSource: string = 'pathtofile.pdf';
}

In my template file (component.html),
<embed [src]="embedSource" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px">

However, the PDF file is not loading in the embed tag. I've double-checked the value of embedSource, and it contains the correct URL path to the PDF file.
Could anyone please help me figure out what might be causing this issue?

The PDF does not get rendered in the Stackblitz, but the below sample code might help. We need to use the DomSanitizer method bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl. So that Angular will trust the URL and load the resource.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  DomSanitizer,
  SafeUrl,
  bootstrapApplication,
} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <embed [src]="embedSource" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600px">
  `,
})
export class App {
  embedSource: SafeUrl = '';

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.embedSource =
      this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/dummy.pdf');
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you. This worked for me. One quick question - What are the potential drawbacks or safety concerns associated with using DOM Sanitizer?

@JagzW Ensure that the asset you load is coming from server only or is a static asset file (only trusted resources should be shown, eg: what you upload in the asset folder is trusted and safe), if you allow the user to upload and view a PDF, ensure you scan it, since there is security risks associate with this reference answer
